# fetching id from login session and populating in home page : php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, session-variables

I have 'user' table which contains username and password details along with user_id which is primary key.

```
user( user_id(pk) , username , password , address, email)
```

When I login to the website, I need to fetch the address and email id from the 'user' table based on the user_id of the username and populate it on home web page.

Please can someone assist me on how to do this ?

Thank You.

Comment: Run a query and get results. Then you could store the results in a session variable or just output them. `select email from user where user_id = ?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you validate the database with your **user_id** & **password** then set :

```
##index.php
$username=$_Post['valuefromform'];
$password=$_Post['valuefromform'];
$result_set="SELECT * FROM user";
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result_set);
if($num_rows!=0)
{
   $result=mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
   if($username==$result['username'] && $password=$result['password'])
   {
       $id=$result['user_id'];
       $_SESSION['id']=$id;
       header("location:index.php?uid=$id");
    }
}
```

You can use `get` method to get the value of `userid`.

```
##home.php

$getid=$_GET['uid'];
echo $getid;
```

Comment: also could you pls assist on how to get the header("location: index.php?uid=$id");  in all pages until I logout?